# Open HTML file from a separate spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a spreadsheet capable of opening an HTML file as a sidebar, but the HTML file is located on a master spreadsheet. Here is the code that I have already for opening the sidebar using an HTML that is in the spreadsheet.

```
function sidebar1() 
{
  var b1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C13').getValue();
  html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(b1).setTitle(b1);
  ui.showSidebar(html);
}
```

Comment: I haven't been able to find any information on the subject so currently this code only works for HTML files in the same spreadsheet

Comment: ui is undefined

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible if you are the current user of that spreadsheet and that spreadsheet is the container of the script because SpreadsheetApp.getUi() as described in the documentation `Returns an instance of the spreadsheet's user-interface environment that allows the script to add features like menus, dialogs, and sidebars.` if a spreadsheet is opened by id or url then there is no user interface

I just thought that if you have two spreadsheets already open it might be possible to call a server side function on one to run a server side function on the other using Apps Script API which might be able to launch a Sidebar on the second sheet.  So maybe I'm wrong.  Give it a try.

Comment: I am trying to simply get the info from the HTML to open on the current sheet. The HTML is just "stored" in a different Spreadsheet, I am trying to do this because I plan to make copies of the sheets and would like to be able to change one thing on the Master Sheet and have that show up on all copies

Comment: By a different sheet do you mean different from the one that is the container of the script?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 spreadsheets. The Master Sheet and the one containing the script

Comment: Then the master spreadsheet when opened by script will not open with a user interface and the script cannot access a user interface that does not exist.  but you don't have to believe me try to do it.  There only four methods to open a spreadsheet and there is only one ui.  So just try it and see what you get.

Comment: So even though the master spreadsheet isn't the one opening the sidebar, it isn't possible to open a sidebar on the script sheet using an HTML file on the master sheet?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment

Comment: Maybe if you have both spreadsheets open and you run a function on another project using APP SCript API you might be able to do it.  I'm not sure.  Give it a try. Personally, I am not interested in trying.

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to open the HTML file into a temporary workbook, and copy the sheet from there into the workbook containing all of them.

Comment: How exactly would that work? I'm new to using separate spreadsheets/workbooks to store information